# Need help to change Custom tab bar (in top) icon when receive a notification from background in iPad app

Tags: ios5, customization, tabbar, custom-component, ipad-2

I am trying to develop a messenger app in ipad 2 where i used a custom tabbar in top of the ipad screen.I need to show an indicator(with icon) in one of the tab when received message from remote party without clicking that tab.i also need to change the selected tab image when starting a chat without tapping the tab.

I already try with self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1"; But it's not working for me because my tabbar is in the top of the ipad screen which is customized and i made my default tabbar hidden at the bottom.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could i ask you why `self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1";` won't work? 
Just cause the tab bar is customized?

But i tried this which works:

```
[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:@"1"];
```

Thanks

Comment: Custom tabbar in top of the window so it doesn't work for me..But thanks :)

Comment: sorry i'm kinda confused. you mean even you use the second method i posted above, still didn't work for the top of the window?